# Cycles table (create row for every change)

Tags: sql, oracle

I need to create a "cycles" table, one row per any update. The below table shows two rows but there can be many assignments under an ID.

I have the below table:

```
ID  class_start class_end enroll_dt reason assignments cat_added 
 1   1/10/19     1/22/19   1/18/19  stop   1/14/19     1/10/19    
 1   1/10/19     1/22/19   1/18/19  stop   1/22/19     1/10/19
```

Expected Results:

```
class_start class_end  start_dt   end_dt    enroll_dt  reason  assignments  cat_added      
 1/10/19               1/10/19    1/13/19                                     1/10/19                                                                                                        
 1/10/19               1/14/19    1/17/19                        1/14/19      1/10/19
 1/10/19               1/18/19    1/21/19     1/18/19            1/14/19      1/10/19
 1/10/19     1/22/19   1/22/19    12/31/9999  1/18/19  stop      1/22/19      1/10/19
```

Comment: Please [edit] to add meaningful code and a problem description here. Posting a [Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example](http://$SITEURL$/help/mcve) that demonstrates your problem would help you get better answers. Thanks!
What is your question?

Comment: Do you have any code that you have already tried for this?

Comment: Do this step by step. Write a query to get the first result row. Write a query to get the second result row. Write a query to get the third result row. At last, glue the results together with `UNION ALL`.

Answer (score 1):

You haven't explained the business logic you're trying to implement. Consequently this solution merely hard-codes **some rules derived from your posted data**.

It uses `connect by level` to spawn multiple rows from one input row (it this case a sub-query based on dual) and tests `level` to conditionally populate the columns in the result set.

```
with cte as (
         select to_date( '1/7/19', 'MM/DD/YY') as class_start,
                to_date( '1/14/19', 'MM/DD/YY') as class_end,
                to_date( '1/9/19', 'MM/DD/YY') as enroll_dt,
                'early' as reason 
         from dual
) 
select cte.class_start
        , case when level = 3 then cte.class_end 
          end as class_end
        , case when level = 1 then cte.class_start
               when level = 2 then cte.enroll_dt
               else cte.class_end - 1
          end as st_dt
        , case when level = 1 then cte.enroll_dt - 1
               when level = 2 then cte.class_end 
               else date '9999-12-31'
          end as end_dt
        , case when level > 1 then cte.enroll_dt end as enroll_dt 
        , case when level = 3 then cte.reason end as reason
from cte
connect by level <= 3
/
```

Probably the biggest gotcha will be if you have more than one input row. In that scenario you will need an identified to link the spawned rows together. Presumably you actual table has an identifier of some sort.

Comment: how can I mange the connect by level <=3. I can have more than 3 rows. I would like the rows to stop when a reason is identified for a row.

Comment: I suspected your actual use case was more complicated than the example you posted, which is why my introduction was very specific about what problem my code solved. As for varying the `level <=3` that rather depends what data you use to know how many rows you need. But given the `level` is hard-coded throughout it's unlikely this solution will work for you anyway.

Comment: *" I would like the rows to stop when a reason is identified for a row"* Your sample input has **one row**. Now you say you have multiple rows. You need to post input data which matches your actual situation as well as required output derived from that sample.

Comment: @John: How can you possibly end up with more than three rows, when there are only three dates in the record? Isn't it three result rows per source row?